# Why is self interpreted as a variable?

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a class called Sand for a game I am making to practice my programming skills, but I can't manage to initiate the pygame sprite class for it, and I get the error

```
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 454, in add
    sprite.add_internal(self)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_internal'
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from particle import part
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

class sand(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    def spawn(xy):
        part(xy, 0, 0, 1, [225, 234, 93])
    def update(self):
        part.phisx(sand)
```

The specific line I'm having trouble with is `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)`

I've tried to put everything in a `def __init__(self):` but then I couldn't call spawn with `sandgroup.add(sand.spawn(xy))`. I have also tried

```
def init(self):
       something
(rest of the code)
```

The result from that was the same as before though.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: the correct method name is `__init__` Share how you use the code, so we understand "couldn't access spawn or update"

Comment: Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Stack Overflow is not a tutorial for beginners. You need to learn the basics first before you can ask a question here.

Comment: *" then I couldn't access spawn or update"*: show the code with which you tried this, and provide the error you get when running it. *"I have also tried... `something`"*: please be concrete. `something` is not going to work... but what did you really code there?

Comment: Apologies. Thank you for the suggestions. I have edited it for clarity.

Comment: Now, if you aren't doing any of your own initialization, you don't need to define your own.  You'll inherit the superclass's initialization automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to their `__init__` needs to be in your own init.  However, that's not the only issue.  `spawn` also needs a "self" parameter.  And where does "part" come from?

BTW, `self` is just a variable.  There's nothing magical about it; it's just a convention.  Python automatically passes the object instance as the first parameter, which we call "self" by convention, but that's not a requirement.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

class sand(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    def spawn(self, xy):
        part(xy, 0, 0, 1, [225, 234, 93])
    def update(self):
        part.phisx(sand)
```

Comment: Typo: `def spawn(self.xy):` should be `def spawn(self, xy):`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the superclass `__init__()` method from the subclass's method. There's no `self` outside the methods. You don't normally specify the superclass by name, you use the built-in function `self()` to refer to it automatically.

The `spawn()` method also need a `self` argument. All methods that aren't annotated with `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` should normally start with the `self` argument.

```
class sand(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)

    def spawn(self, xy):
        part(xy, 0, 0, 1, [225, 234, 93])

    def update(self):
        part.phisx(sand)
```